# Finite Groups - order of the element divides order of the Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Going through Christof Paar's book on cryptography. In his chapter on DHKE, he has the following

[image]

The theorem itself talks only about Finite Groups ("Let G be a finite group")

But when he talks about the second property - he says - "The second property is very useful in practice. It says that in a **cyclic** group only element orders which divide the group cardinality exist."

How is saying that it's only for cyclic groups? Shouldn't it be "It says that in a **finite** group only element orders which divide the group cardinality exist."

Comment: You are correct that the Theorem covers all finite groups.  Perhaps the author simply wished to draw attention to the special case of cyclic groups.

Comment: It seems like in both sentences the author may have meant to say "finite" instead of "cyclic".